# Show that there is a invertible continuous function $h: \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Q}$ such that $h(−1) = 0$, $h(0) = 1$, $h(1) = −1$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that there is a invertible continuous function $h: \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Q}$ such that $h(−1) = 0, h(0) = 1, h(1) = −1$.

My attempt so far has been to try to split the rationals in [0,1] into two groups with no gaps, something like $\{p/q \in \mathbb{Q}:\operatorname{hcf}(p,q)=1,\ p \text{ even}\}$ and $\{p/q \in \mathbb{Q}:\operatorname{hcf}(p,q)=1,\ p \text{ odd}\}$. Then I need a continuous map from $(-1,0)$ into one of these, and from $(0,1)$ into the other. I don't know if any of this makes sense but hopefully somebody can push me in the right direction. Thanks ;)

Comment: Consider intervals $(\alpha,\beta)$ with irrational endpoints.

Comment: @DanielFischer, you can construct a continuous function with the specified values that way, but how do you assure that it's invertible? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: To insure invertibility, it would be enough to know of one continuous function that maps every rational number to a rational whose numerator is even and another that maps every rational to a rational whose numerator is odd.  I don't know any such functions. It's easy to find a continuous function mapping every rational to a square of a rational, but how do you find a continuous function mapping every rational number to a rational that is not a square of any rational? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Similar to [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274485/is-every-homeomorphism-of-mathbbq-monotone), @MichaelHardy.

Comment: Did you get an idea from the question I linked to?

Comment: Do you want a bijection or just an injection?

Comment: I've edited my answer and then undeleted it.  It now gives a continuous bijection $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ with the three specified values. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number between $0$ and $1$.

For $x\in\mathbb Q$ let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x<-\alpha-2 \text{ or }x>\alpha+1, \\[8pt]
x+1 & \text{if } -\alpha-2 < x < \alpha, \\[8pt]
x-2 & \text{if } \alpha < x < \alpha+1.
\end{cases}
$$

This is continuous at every point in $\mathbb Q$ and is one-to-one and onto.

To verify that it is one-to-one and onto you need to chase the piecewise definition around a bit:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{domain} & \text{image} \\
\hline
(-\infty,\alpha-2)\cap\mathbb Q & (-\infty,\alpha-2)\cap\mathbb Q \\
(\alpha-2,\alpha)\cap\mathbb Q & (\alpha-1,\alpha+1)\cap\mathbb Q \\
(\alpha,\alpha+1) \cap\mathbb Q & (\alpha-2,\alpha-1)\cap\mathbb Q \\
(\alpha+1,\infty)\cap\mathbb Q & (\alpha+1,\infty)\cap\mathbb Q
\end{array}
$$
The four pieces of the image don't intersect and their union is all of $\mathbb Q$.